Show that the set $ab - 1 $is dense in natural numbers
How do I show that the following set $S$ is dense in natural numbers: $2$ and $3$ belong to $S$ and for $a \neq b \in S, ab - 1 \in S$?
Edit 1: Dense in natural numbers means that the set takes up a positive proportion of natural numbers, for example even numbers have density $1/2$ and prime numbers are not dense in $\Bbb N$. My progress has been that for $n \lt 1 \text{ billion}$ the proportion is more than $50$%.

Please edit to show your effort.  That said, it looks like every element in $S$ is an integer so...

Please [edit] the question to tell us what "dense in the natural numbers" means and to show us your worl so far on the problem.

Oh, I missed the "dense in natural numbers" bit.  What on earth does that mean?

a and b need to be different

And it makes perfect sense to talk about the density of $S$ as in $|{s\in S: s \le n}|/n$.

Indeed it does.

There is nothing on OEIS on this particular set. I think the problem is very hard, I found it in an old Russian book of unsolved problems…

2, 3, 5, 9, 14, 17, 26, 27…

https://www.erdosproblems.com/424 says the problem is open.

Yeah I know, some vague ideas would be great

If you check out OEIS : https://oeis.org/A005244.
You'll find in the link: https://www.erdosproblems.com/424 where the problem of proving that this set has positive density is presented as open. It does show a nice proof that the natural density is no more than $2/3$. So this problem was open in 1980. It would be great to learn if we've made some progress.
